# Electron app won't run. cant figure out why

Tags: npm, electron

when typing npm start it gives me this error:

```
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! helloworld@1.0.0 start: `electron .`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the helloworld@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
```

here is the package.json

```
{
  "name": "helloworld",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "my app",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "electron ."
  },
  "author": "kamalyaka",
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Could you provide us full log and content of `package.json`? There are missing dependencies and actual error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to first install all the dependencies.
Try executing

```
npm install
```

first in your project directory.
After the dependencies are installed then you can execute

```
npm start
```

which will start your electron app.